# Font-size not working when resizing the page

Tags: css, resize, media

I am trying to inject using adobe target the following code in our work website:

```
//Texto Titulo
let [textoparausuario] = [...document.querySelectorAll('.rst-margin')].filter(item => item.innerText === 'Abra su Cuenta en menos de 5 minutos');
textoparausuario.innerHTML = '<div><div class="sin-salir-de-casa"> <p class="texto1">Sin salir de casa y en menos de 5 minutos</p><p class="texto2">En la distancia, más juntos que nunca</p></div><div class="borderColor"><div style="display: flex;align-items: baseline;"><img src="https://ingdirectspain.experiencecloud.adobe.com/content/dam/mac/ingdirectspain/tx-sin-salir-de-casa/solidicon-information-alert-i.png/_jcr_content/renditions/cq5dam.web.1280.1280.png?ch_ck=1586246579000" style="padding-left: 8px;"><p class="texto3">Para tu tranquilidad, puedes abrir la Cuenta de manera 100% digital </p></div></div>';

var csstitulo = '<style>.sin-salir-de-casa{font-family:INGMe;font-size:24px!important;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-style:normal;line-height:1.33;letter-spacing:normal;text-align:center;color:#333;padding-bottom:32px;max-width:1128px}.texto1{font-size:24px!important;line-height:32px!important;margin:0;padding:0!important}.texto2{font-size:24px!important;line-height:32px!important;margin:0;padding:0!important}.borderColor{border:solid #ff6200;border-width:1px!important;max-width:1128px;border-radius:4px;border:solid 2px #559bd1;background-color:#fff}.texto3{font-family:INGMe;font-size:16px!important;text-align:justify;font-weight:normal;font-stretch:normal;font-style:normal;letter-spacing:normal;color:#333;line-height:24px!important;margin:0;padding:8px 16px 8px 8px!important} @media screen and (max-width:55.250em){.sin-salir-de-casa{max-width:732px;font-weight:normal}.borderColor{max-width:732px;}.texto3{max-width:680px}}@media screen and (max-width:18.5em){.sin-salir-de-casa{max-width:296px;font-weight:normal;font-size:16px !important}.borderColor{max-width:296px}.texto3{max-width:224px}.texto1{font-size:16px!important; text-align:center!important}.texto2{font-size:16px!important;text-align:center!important}}</style>';
textoparausuario.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', csstitulo); 

//fixpadding
fixpadding= document.querySelector("#container-steps-flow-process-list > div.container-steps-flow-step-content.active > div > div > div.txt-c > div > div > div.row.account-prospect-welcome-timer-container > div > p");
fixpadding.style.paddingTop ="0px";
```

It works fine. The page has it default style that´s why I use !important so it won´t use it and only apply the style I am writting. The problem is that when I resize the page to media screen 18.5 .texto1 and texto2 is not getting the font-size: 16px but it is getting 24px. How can I make the text be 16px instead 24px?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
@media screen and (max-width:55.250em) and (min-width:18.51em)
```

for the first media query.

Comment: I did, and also added one @media to the desktop size but it is still getting 24px. Is it because the !important?

Comment: afaik, the !important shouldn't cause the issue, given the order of the style rules. but if you placed another applying rule (+ !important) below the last media query with the desired font-size, it would override it. so, is there any other font-sizing CSS with !important being added / rendered after that last rule?

Comment: Yes, I added !important for media query for desktop(24px), for tablet (24px) and mobile (16px). If I don´t add it the text will get the page style but if I add it only get the 24px font size style. I don´t know what to do.

Comment: but did you add any of the 24px rules *before* or *after* the 16px rules? if both the desktop and the tablet rule come before the mobile rule, and nothing else making the font 24px comes after it, then that should not be the problem.